# ffmpeg works with laptop webcam but not with android camera

Tags: android, node.js, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am working on Macbook with M1 Chip with this ffmpeg version locally installed.

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers 
built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
```

With this, I am able to use my laptop's webcam as input and do my ffmpeg work.

Following command is what worked (avfoundation was needed for OSX)

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i 0:0 \
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:v libx264 -profile:v high \
-crf 32 -ar 44100 \
-c:a aac \
-filter:v:0 scale=w=480:h=360 \
-utc_timing_url "https://time.akamai.com/?iso" \
-segment_time 8 \
-f dash ${path.join(__dirname, "/output/sample.mpd")}
```

Now, I am trying to use my android front camera as an input.

But, it is not working. (Errors are mainly in & around camera_index)

I am trying the following command and facing error.

```
ffmpeg -f android_camera -camera_index 0 -framerate 30 -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v\
libx264 -profile:v high -c:a aac -filter:v:0 scale=w=480:h=360 \
-utc_timing_url "https://time.akamai.com/?iso" -segment_time 8 \
-f dash ${path.join(__dirname, "/output/sample.mpd")}
```

This is the stacktrace of the whole error log: https://www.diffchecker.com/Mnnghg7M/

1. What is the correct command for android camera as input ?
2. Do all stable versions of ffmpeg work with android or any limitations ?

Comment: I don't see an input declared in the command `-i ...`

Comment: Can you guide me on that part please.
I don't see it in documentation here for android_camera.
http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/android_005fcamera.htm.gz
@Gyan

Comment: Right after `-framerate 30` add `-i dummy` (and remove `-map 0:a`)

Comment: @Gyan I tried as you suggested.

`ffmpeg -f android_camera -camera_index 0 -framerate 30 -i dummy -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -c:a aac -filter:v:0 scale=w=480:h=360 -utc_timing_url "https://time.akamai.com/?iso" -segment_time 8 -f dash ${path.join(
        __dirname,
        "/output/sample.mpd"
      )}`



But I am getting 

`Unrecognized option 'camera_index'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: @Gyan Did you get a get a chance to look at this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rerun with -report and share report.